# JFrame how to detect whether deiconification is completed

Tags: java, swing, jframe

when I use WindowListener, I can detect when window goes iconified/deiconified. My problem: I need to show special headless tool-window for my main frame. When frame goes iconified - I need to hide the tool-window (works good). When frame goes deiconified I need to show it again. The last thing works only partially: the tool-window comes before the main frame is completly deiconified due to the animation delay. Of course, I can add a little time-out, but it sounds bad for me because different OS may have different animation lag. So which event should I listen to get notified, when window is completely deiconified?

Here is MCVE

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

/**
 * <code>DeiconifyTest</code>.
 */
public class DeiconifyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Main frame");
        frm.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea()));
        frm.setSize(600, 500);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        JWindow nestedWindow = new JWindow(frm);
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Test");
        text.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        text.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        nestedWindow.add(text);
        nestedWindow.setSize(100, 80);
        nestedWindow.setLocation(610, 0);
        nestedWindow.setVisible(true);
        WindowListener wl = new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
                nestedWindow.setVisible(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
                // nestedWindow is visible before the main frame is deiconified
                nestedWindow.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        frm.addWindowListener(wl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// nestedWindow is visible before the main frame is deiconified
nestedWindow.setVisible(true);
```

Try wrapping the above code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to place the logic at the end of the EDT so hopefully the main window is deiconified first.